# Expo: Change android emulator to a different device

Tags: expo, adb

I can see these devices when running "adb devices".

```
C:\Windows\system32>adb devices
List of devices attached
1WMHH816LN0397  unauthorized
emulator-5554   device
```

I want to run my Expo project on the emulator, however whenever I run "expo start" I get this error:

```
This computer is not authorized for developing on Device 1WMHH816LN0397. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/authorize-android-device
```

How can I run the project on the correct device?

I'm unable to unplug or disable the 1WM device, as I can not figure out what it is. I have restarted all relevant software, as well as unplugged everything connected to my computer. I can not get rid of it. I'm unauthorized to get information about the 1WM device:

```
C:\Windows\system32>adb -s 1WMHH816LN0397 shell getprop
adb.exe: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

I have attempted to restart everything I can think of, including adb:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

What options do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just curious if you have a Quest 2? Quick google search says that it starts with 1WMHH.

Regardless, you can do `expo run:android -d` and it will give you a dropdown of devices, and you can choose your simulator that way.

Comment: Yeah this is it. I didn't realize it was still connected.